# Background image on Header not showing

Tags: html, css, image, background

I've just started a new document testing some skills out. In attempt to make a hero image with text overlay which features call to action buttons my background image isn't showing.

I know it's there but it seems to be pushed upwards. When I inspect element and put the padding to 200px it shows but directly putting the code in the file doesn't bring it out.

```
//CSS

* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
color: #555;
font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 20px;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.row {
max-width: 1140px;
}

.header {
background: url(img/hero.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position:center;
}

.hero-text-box {
position: absolute;
width: 1140px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;  
}

//HTML

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/fluid-    grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,300,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Test</title>
     </head>


    <body>
        <header>

            <div class="hero-text-box">
            <h1>Welcome to my site</h1>
            <a href="#">Call me</a>
            <a href="#">Show me more</a>

            </div>

        </header>

</body>



</html>
```

**Folder Structure**

```
+ index.htm
+ css
  + img
  + style.css
+ js
  + scripts.js
+ img
+ data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `.header` to `header`:

```
header {
  background: url(img/hero.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

**Missing Image Issue**

Change back to `img/hero.jpg`. The next thing you need to do is about the `hv`. It is wrong. Either put it as `vh`, which is also not supported, so, better use:

```
header {
    background-image: url(img/hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

**Preview**

[image]

And the `translate` is what is affecting:

```
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
```

See output: **http://output.jsbin.com/furumogoxe**

So I have made some changes too to the CSS using another way:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
}

header {
  background: url(img/hero.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center;
}

.hero-text-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1140px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;  
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,300,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<header>
  <div class="hero-text-box">
    <h1>Welcome to my site</h1>
    <a href="#">Call me</a>
    <a href="#">Show me more</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Ah, that's sorted the formatting of the text but I still can't get the image to load.

Comment: @MatthewPeabody Please keep the image with respect to your CSS path.

Comment: I have a css folder with an img folder in that with the hero image. The image is there as when I change the code whilst inspecting the element in the browser it shows up.

Comment: @MatthewPeabody Can you tell me all the paths?

Comment: Sure. 
In the root folder I have; Resources and Vendors folders and index.html.
In the Resources folder I have css, data, img and js folders. 
In the css folder I have style.css and an image folder.

Comment: I've changed the file structure but still not luck getting the image to show up.

Comment: @MatthewPeabody See the updated question. Can you update your file structure in that? I did that for you!

Comment: Yeah, that's how it is now. viewing the project in the browser shows a little blue line where the image should be squished to the top while the text is all nice and centered.

Comment: I've tried everything and I still can't get that stupid image to come down :/

Comment: @MatthewPeabody **Solution:** Use `url(../img/hero.jpg)`

Comment: @MatthewPeabody What's happening? Works?

Comment: Nothing happens lol When I hover over the code for it there's a blue line at the top like 1px high. 
If I inspect the element in my browser and change the height of the image to 200px it's there. If I do it in the editor, nothing shows.

Comment: @MatthewPeabody Do one thing... Go to http://plnkr.co and upload all your files, or please, upload your files and share it here. `:)`

Comment: I officially love you! :D Thanks a million!